# GtkCellRendererText - use "ellipsize" together with "wrap-width"

Tags: c, gtk3, cellrenderer, word-wrap, ellipsize

I need to break some generic text into multiple lines using a [GtkCellRendererText](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkCellRendererText.html).
If the text exceeds 3 lines, I would like to ellipsize it.

So here is my attempt, which does not work so well.

```
  ...
  g_object_set (G_OBJECT (my_text_renderer),
                "ellipsize", PANGO_ELLIPSIZE_END,
                "single-paragraph-mode", TRUE,
                "wrap-mode", PANGO_WRAP_WORD_CHAR,
                "wrap-width", 30,
                "width-chars", 40,
                "xpad", 5,
                NULL);
```

It works fine if I only use "ellipsize", and it works fine if I only use "wrap-width" ... but both together seems to be a problem.

I found [this tutorial](https://wiki.gnome.org/HowDoI/Labels) which suggest to use "gtk_label_set_lines", however I cannot do this, since I dont use a label.